# T-SQL choosing single row dependent on column condition and frequency in table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, merge, conditional-statements

I have an issue that has arisen from merging two tables, and I wonder if there's a neat way of solving inside T-SQL.

```
--Example data
CREATE TABLE #pets 
(
    pet_id VARCHAR(MAX),
    cost DEC(10,0),
    sold VARCHAR(MAX)
);

INSERT INTO #pets
VALUES ('dog',10,'yes'),
       ('dog',10,'yes'),
       ('dog',10,'no'),
       ('cat',5,NULL),
       ('mouse',15,NULL),
       ('mouse',15,'no')

SELECT * FROM #pets

--------------------------
pet_id  cost  sold
--------------------------
dog     10    yes
dog     10    yes
dog     10    no
cat      5    NULL
mouse   15    NULL
mouse   15    no
```

The output I would like obeys the following rules (in order):

1. If only one row with given pet_id: keep
2. If rows are exact duplicates: delete till only one
3. If multiple rows with same pet_id: choose the one in following hierarchy "no", "yes", NULL - so "no" being the best option

Hence the output I want is:

```
pet_id cost sold
-----------------
dog    10   no
cat     5   NULL
mouse  15   no
```

Anything I try inadvertently effects another row I didn't want to.

I can remove duplicates with the following:

```
SELECT *
FROM #pets
GROUP BY pet_id, cost, sold
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 

UNION 

SELECT *
FROM #pets
GROUP BY pet_id, cost, sold
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1 

-----------------
pet_id  cost  sold
-----------------
cat     5     NULL
dog    10     yes
dog    10     no
mouse  15     NULL
mouse  15     no
```

Which isn't that elegant but gets me half-way. However if I then try to remove any where sold is NULL, I'll delete the "cat" row which I don't want to.

EDIT: it was pointed out my example wasn't complete (including the conditions) so is now updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will give what you need.

```
SELECT pet_id, cost, CASE MIN(CASE sold WHEN 'no' then 1 WHEN 'yes' then 2 ELSE 3 END) 
                        WHEN 1 THEN 'no'
                        WHEN 2 THEN 'yes'
                        ELSE NULL END sold  
FROM #pets
GROUP BY pet_id, cost
```

Result:

```
pet_id cost     sold
------ -------- ----
cat    5        NULL
dog    10       no
mouse  15       no
```

Comment: This will work for the sample data provided in the question, but that sample data doesn't include at least one more possible case. Add a dog with cost 10 and sold "no". See what happens.

Comment: I thought the same case. But in the question, the need is `choose the one with sold column not NULL` and MAX chooses the one that is not null.

Comment: @luke_shaw I updated my answer. Now it is little bit complex :)

Answer (score 0):

A simple straight answer would be this:

```
    ;WITH cte_pets 
     AS ( 
        -- remove exact dublicates and mark the ones with sold column NULL/not NULL 
        SELECT pet_id, 
               cost, 
               sold, 
               keep_it = Row_number() 
                          OVER (partition BY pet_id, cost ORDER BY sold DESC) 
         FROM   #pets 
         GROUP  BY pet_id, cost, sold) 
SELECT pet_id, 
       cost, 
       sold 
FROM   cte_pets 
WHERE  keep_it = 1
```

You still would have problems with key duplicates ... meaning yous key is pet name and cost or just pet name.

i.e if sample table is populated like this

```
INSERT INTO #pets
VALUES ('dog',10,'yes'),
       ('dog',11,'yes'),
       ('dog',11,'no')
```

end result would have 2 dogs with different prices and only the sold 'yes' would be visible.

```
pet_id  cost sold 
------ ----- ---------
dog      10  yes
dog      11  yes
```

Comment: If you add another row to the table with `dog`, `10` and `no` as it's values, that's going to delete too many rows.

Comment: Thanks - that's great! I think you are right @Zohar Peled, as it happens in my situation I do only want one row per pet_id (would have to choose hierarchy of the values in sold) but now am interested on the solution to the question I actually posed

Comment: The sample data you've entered should return all three rows, according to the rules specified on the question...

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would do it:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
SELECT  pet_id, 
        cost, 
        sold,
        COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY pet_id) as petIdCount,
        -- order doesn't matter as all columns are the same
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY pet_id, cost, sold ORDER BY @@SPID) as duplicateRn
FROM #pets
)

DELETE 
FROM cte
WHERE duplicateRn > 1
OR (petIdCount > 1 AND sold IS NULL);
```

It looks cumbersome on a first glance, but it will only delete the records you want.

Your sample data is incomplete. It doesn't include at least one edge case where you have three rows with the same pet id and cost, and two different values in the `sold` column.
Adding a record with `dog`, `10` and `no` values, this script would keep one record for the `dog` `10` `yes` as well as this record.

[See a live demo on rextester](https://rextester.com/CEUCU36024) (with the added row)

Having said that, deleting the duplicates is only half the job. Once you've deleted the duplicates you should add unique constraints (or indexes) to your table, to prevent entering new duplicates.